# How to remove horizontal scrollbar from slick.js

Tags: javascript, css, slider, slick.js

I am implemented one slider by use Slick.js. It works, but it shows the horizontal scrollbar and I can't find how to fix it.

I have tried with `overflow:hidden` and `box-sizing: border-box;` but not worked.
Could you please help me to get rid of the horizontal scrollbar?

Script and css attached below

```js
(function(ng, $) {
 'use strict';

 ng.module('cfrRefugeeApp').directive('slider',slider);
 slider.$inject = ['App.config','$timeout','$window','$rootScope'];

 function slider(AppConfig, $timeout,$window,$rootScope) {
  return {
   restrict: 'A',
   scope: {
         item: '='
      },
   link: function(scope, element, attr) {
    var $el = ng.element(element);

    var itemId = attr.itemid;
    var itemType = attr.itemtype;
    var sectionId = attr.sectionid;
    var $sliderEl;
    var $slideshow, $slider, $scrollindicator;
    var height, top, bottom;
    var scrollY;
    var currentSlideNum = 0;
    var currentSection = undefined;
    var active = false;
    var isTouch = AppConfig.isTouchDevice;
    var $header, $line;
    var init = false;
    var built = false;
    var dimensionsSet = false;
    var noChangeCountToEnd = 100;
    var w = ng.element($window);
    var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight || w.height();
    var animate = false;
    var waitingToAnimate = false;
    var triggerItem = undefined;
    var triggerNum = undefined;

    
    var setElem = function(){
     $sliderEl = $el.find('.slider-el');
     setResolutions();
             setSlideshow();
    }

    var resolutionsState = function(slick){
     if(slick.currentSlide == 0){
      if($header && $header.hasClass('dragged')) $header.removeClass('dragged');
      if($line && $line.hasClass('wider')) $line.removeClass('wider'); 
      slick.$prevArrow.fadeOut();

     }else{
      if($line && !$line.hasClass('wider')) $line.addClass('wider');
      slick.$prevArrow.fadeIn();
      
     }
     if(slick.currentSlide == slick.slideCount - 1){
      slick.$nextArrow.fadeOut();
     }else{
      slick.$nextArrow.fadeIn();
     }
    }

    var setResolutions = function(){
            if(itemType == 'resolutions'){
              $header = $el.find('.resolution-head');
              $line = $el.find('.resolution-line');

              $slider = $sliderEl.slick({
                arrows: true,
                slidesToScroll: 2,
                variableWidth: true,
                infinite: false,
         cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1)',
         speed: 800,
         responsive: [
          {
           breakpoint: 1280,
       settings: {
        slidesToScroll: 1
       }
          }
         ],
                nextArrow: '<div class="resolution-drag next"><svg viewBox="0 0 11 18" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> <g fill-rule="nonzero" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="square"> <polyline points="2 2 8.25418658 8.75198312 2 15.5"></polyline> </g> </svg></div>',
                prevArrow: '<div class="resolution-drag previous"><svg viewBox="0 0 11 18" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> <g fill-rule="nonzero" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="square">  <polyline points="9.74581342 3 3 9.75198312 9.74581342 16.5"></polyline> </g> </svg></div>',
              }).on('swipe', function(event, slick, direction){
               
                 resolutionsState(slick);
              })
              .on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
                
               resolutionsState(slick);
              })
              .on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){

                 if($header && !$header.hasClass('dragged')) $header.addClass('dragged');

              });
            }
          }



          var setSlideshow = function(){
            if(itemType == 'slideshow'){
              var $parent = $el.parent();

              $scrollindicator = $parent.find('.slider-scrollindicator');

              $sliderEl.on('init', function(){
               intervalResize();
               console.log('slick init');
              });

              $slideshow = $sliderEl.slick({
                arrows: false,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                infinite: false,
                draggable: false,
                dots: isTouch,
         cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1)',
         speed: 1000
              });

              $sliderEl.on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
               animate = false;
               
              });
              $parent.find('.slider-skip').on('click', function(){
               window.scrollTo(0, bottom);
              });
            }
          }

          var checkAnimate = function(){
           if(!animate){
            $sliderEl.slick('slickGoTo', currentSlideNum);
           }else{
            $timeout(function(){
             checkAnimate();
            }, 200);
           }
          }

          /* resize */
          var intervalResize = function(){
            var interval,
              timeout,
              end,
              lastTop,
              lastBottom,
              lastHeight,
              noChangeCount;
            dimensionsSet = false;

              end = function () {
                 
                  clearInterval(interval);

                  interval = null;
                  timeout = null;
                  dimensionsSet = true;
                  onResize();
                  
              };

              interval = setInterval(function () {
                  setTopBottom();
                  if (top === lastTop && height === lastHeight && bottom === lastBottom) {
                      noChangeCount++;

                      if (noChangeCount === noChangeCountToEnd) {
                          // The interval resolved the issue first.
                          //if(itemNum == 20) console.log('interval end '+ height);
                          end();
                      }
                  } else {
                      lastTop = top;
                      lastBottom = bottom;
                      lastHeight = height;
                      noChangeCount = 0;
                  }
              },1);
          }

          var setTopBottom = function(){
            if(!scrollY) scrollY = 0;
            // var rect = $el[0].getBoundingClientRect();
            // top = rect.top + scrollY;
            // height = $el.outerHeight();
            // bottom = top + height;
            height = $el.outerHeight();
            top = $el.offset().top;
            bottom = top + height;
          }

          var onResize = function(){
              checkVisible();
          }

          var checkVisible = function(){
           if(scrollY > top && scrollY < bottom - viewportHeight){
            var percentScrolled = (scrollY - top)/(height - viewportHeight);

            // var num = Math.round(percentScrolled * 8);

            // if(num !== currentSlideNum){
            //  currentSlideNum = num;
            //  if(!animate){
            //   animate = true;
            //   $sliderEl.slick('slickGoTo', currentSlideNum);
            //  }else{
            //   checkAnimate();
            //  }
             
            // }
            
            $scrollindicator.css('transform', 'scaleX('+ percentScrolled +')');
           }
          }

          var setActive = function(){
           active = true;
           if(!built){
      setElem();
      built = true;
     }else{
      if(!isTouch && itemType == 'slideshow') intervalResize();
     }
          }

          var getItemDetails = function(id){
           var arr = id.split('-');
           triggerItem = arr[0] + arr[1];
           triggerNum = parseInt(arr[2].substr(-1), 10);
          }

          var checkTrigger = function(id){
           if(itemType == 'slideshow' && built){
            getItemDetails(id);
            if(triggerItem = itemId){
             if(currentSlideNum !== triggerNum){
              currentSlideNum = triggerNum;
              if(!animate){
               animate = true;
               $sliderEl.slick('slickGoTo', currentSlideNum);
              }else{
               checkAnimate();
              }
             }
            }
           }
          }


          /* LISTENING TO EVENTS ----------------------------------------- */

    scope.$on('sectionItem::active', function($event, args) {
     currentSection = args.sectionId;
             if (init && currentSection == sectionId) {
      setActive();
     }else{
      active = false;
     }
          });

    scope.$on('winEvents::scroll', function($event, args){
     scrollY = args.scrollY;
           if(!isTouch && itemType == 'slideshow' && active) checkVisible();
          });

          scope.$on('winEvents::resize', function($event, args){
           viewportHeight = args.height;
           if(!isTouch && itemType == 'slideshow' && active) intervalResize();
          });
          

          scope.$on('triggerItem::inview', function($event, args) {
          
        
         
            checkTrigger(args.triggerId);

         
           
       });


    /* TIMEOUTs ----------------------------------------- */

          $timeout(function() {
             init = true;

             if(currentSection == undefined){
      $rootScope.$broadcast('slider::init');
     }else if(currentSection == sectionId){
      setActive();
     } 
          }, 500);

   }
  };
 }
})(angular, jQuery);
```

```html
/* Slider */

.slick-slider {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
    touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
.slick-list {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    &:focus {
        outline: none;
    }

    &.dragging {
        cursor: pointer;
        cursor: hand;
    }
}
.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    &:before,
    &:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
    }

    &:after {
        clear: both;
    }

    .slick-loading & {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
.slick-slide {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
    [dir="rtl"] & {
        float: right;
    }
    img {
        display: block;
    }
    &.slick-loading img {
        display: none;
    }

    display: none;

    &.dragging img {
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .slick-initialized & {
        display: block;
    }

    .slick-loading & {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .slick-vertical & {
        display: block;
        height: auto;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
    }
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
    display: none;
}

.slick-dots {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.slick-dots li
{
    position: relative;

    display: inline-block;

    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0;

    cursor: pointer;
}
.slick-dots li button
{
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;

    display: block;

    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    padding: 5px;

    cursor: pointer;

    color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}
.slick-dots li button:hover,
.slick-dots li button:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-dots li button:hover:before,
.slick-dots li button:focus:before
{
    opacity: 1;
}
.slick-dots li button:before
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border-radius: 50%;

    content: '';
    background: #000;
    text-align: center;

    opacity: .25;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.slick-dots li.slick-active button:before
{
    opacity: .75;
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The previous and the next arrow in slick slider creates horizontal bar because it adds extra width to the slider component and to avoid this use position relative to override slick CSS .

```
.slick-prev {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slick-next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```